# I am resigning as a moderator

Tags: discussion

it's been an honour to help the bioinfo.SE to be a clean, constructive and kind space for sharing our expertise in bioinformatics. However, I recently quit my job and taking some time off and I don't think I would be able to continue to be moderator for quite long period of time, hence the resignation.

I am not leaving bioinformatics, I will be around at some point. I just need my time off and I think it's a good time to leave the mod role for more eager members of our community :-).

Thank you all for your contributions, it's been a great to witness the community coming together and be part of it.

--- edit ---

Thank you for the support! But I feel I should clarify. I am fine, I resigned because I have another job lined up for this autumn. I really just wanted to get a proper break before I get back to the working life.

Comment: Good luck and keep your chin up.  We all go through the same feelings now and then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very sorry to hear about this @KamilSJaron and thank you for all the time and dedication you have put into the community.

Bioinformatics and the broader world of computation is on a strong upward trajectory and its fantastic (and not surprising) you've a new post lined up.

I am glad you are sticking around Bioinfo. SE. If you're back to the millstone in the autumn, reassess then perhaps?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Now I realized how misleading was what I wrote. I am really alright, I just want the break. Thank you for the support though!

Comment: Thanks @KamilSJaron I've updated my response. Thanks for informing us.